# I have to apply spelling checker in flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

Whenever any text is entered by user in text-area.
it should be have in correct format or in correct spelling.

I have find out the way in flex 4, but i want to do it in flex 3.
please anyone tell me how can solve this problem?

Thanks

Nidhi

Comment: What about the Flex 4 solution you found makes it unusable in Flex 3?

Comment: I have used "AdobeSpellingUI.swc" file                               Try to use spelling check in text area using "SpellUI.enableSpelling(textInputArea,"en_US")"                       But it's not working. please help me

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the answer I posted? If it helps solve your problem, you can upvote it by clicking on the ^ arrow and flag it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark icon next to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try [Adobe's Squiggly library](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/squiggly/). It support spell checking in Flex 3, Flex 4 and AIR.

They posted a [demo of the library in action](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/squiggly/demo/#).